# Adding rel="next" & rel="prev" for paginated archives

Tags: seo, headers

Does someone perhaps know a plugin or snippet (besides Yoast's WordPress SEO) to accomplish this perhaps? [Pagination with rel=“next” and rel=“prev”](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html)

The only thing I've come across seems to be an 3-month old [Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18660) ticket.

Comment: you can do this by using query and append it

Comment: @ntechi, thank you for your quick reply.
My guess is however this answers about 99,9% of all questions listed here. I have to admit I was hoping for something a bit more detailed.

Comment: your aim is to add a rel in next and previous link?

Comment: The one Google [advises](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html), yes. Not the ones that are currently used by WordPress default.

Comment: @CorvanNoorloos The one _Google advices_ is **in the head** section, not directly at the link element...

Comment: @kaiser, yes, that's what I'm trying to accomplish. For as far as I was aware it's what's the article and trac-ticket was about.

Comment: I just wondered about the answer by @ntechi and your comment.

Comment: @kaiser, perhaps I should have been more clear. I was definitely looking for a head section solution. The main difference leaving out the page title, and making it available for pagination. Mostly not my own code, but this was what I was looking for https://gist.github.com/1494942

Comment: Ah, ok. So we know each other from rilwis meta-box class. Ok, what exactly is the problem with your snippet? Btw: If you add `<?php` at the beginning of the gist, you'll get syntax highlighting too.

Comment: I think this is the solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/307182/64590

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add <link rel="next"> and <link rel="prev"> in the header while looping over custom query in page template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307109/add-link-rel-next-and-link-rel-prev-in-the-header-while-looping-over-cus)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try putting this snippet in your functions.php

```
<?php
function rel_next_prev(){
    global $paged;

    if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) { ?>
        <link rel="prev" href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link( $paged - 1 ); ?>" /><?php
    }

    if ( get_next_posts_link() ) { ?>
        <link rel="next" href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link( $paged +1 ); ?>" /><?php
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_next_prev' );
?>
```

And if you don't want the next and prev rel links to show up on the singular pages just wrap the output markup in a `!is_singular()` if condition

Comment: Thanks @Joshua, this works even better than the gist mentioned above!

Comment: I would recommend using `is_archive()` instead of `! is_singular()`

Comment: `get_next_posts_link()` not working without the `max_num_pages` parameter, how can I get this variable in functions.php? am I missing something ?

Comment: Does ### if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) ### PHP syntax mean: replace the function get_previous_posts_link() with the function that follows?

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much does exactly that, as a plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pagination-rel-links/

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.

Answer (score -3):

Ok then this will be a good solution:

```
$('YOUR_PAGINATION_A_ID').attr('rel', 'next');
$('YOUR_PAGINATION_A_ID').attr('rel', 'prev');
```

Try this, it might help you.

Comment: If I understand correct you're suggesting to let JavaScript handle this?
Since Google or any other search engine doesn't understand JavaScript, I doubt this would be the ideal solution.

Comment: yaa that would be, better would be you edit that PHP code itself or wait for another answer

Comment: It always be a good practice to do it server-side..

Comment: This is pretty useless for SEO