# get_next_posts_link not working without parameter max_num_pages

Tags: functions, pagination, seo, paginate-links

I have a custom search page (`searchpage.php`) using pagination, and I am tring to add lines like below dynamically to my `header.php` inside `<head></head>` tag for better [pagination SEO](https://www.ayima.com/knowledge/guides/conquering-pagination-guide.html).

```
<link rel="prev" href="https://www.example.com/search/cats/page/2/">
<link rel="next" href="https://www.example.com/search/cats/page/4/">
```

While doing this, I have used below code mentioned [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/36834/112778) in **functions.php**.

```
<?php
function rel_next_prev(){
    global $paged;    
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) { ?>
        <link rel="prev" href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link( $paged - 1 ); ?>" /><?php
    }    
    if ( get_next_posts_link() ) { ?>
        <link rel="next" href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link( $paged +1 ); ?>" /><?php
    }    
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_next_prev' );
?>
```

`get_previous_posts_link()` works fine, but `get_next_posts_link` doesn't work, after some investigation I believe it requires `max_num_pages` parameter to work.

Now I am not able to get `max_num_pages` because it is in `searchpage.php`.

Comment: You need to run your custom query before wp_head runs.

Comment: @Milo please write it as answer, and I'll accept it. Moving my custom query before `get_header();` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I spent the night working on the same issue. What I did was.

```
<?php
function rel_next_prev(){
    global $paged;
    $default_posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

    if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) { ?>
        <link rel="prev" href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link( $paged - 1 ); ?>" /><?php
    }    
    if ( get_next_posts_link(null,$default_posts_per_page) ) { ?>
        <link rel="next" href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link( $paged +1 ); ?>" /><?php
    }    
}
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head');
add_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_next_prev' );
?>
```

It's imperative to pass arguments on `get_next_posts_link`, first one null, and the second one an int, just use `get_option( 'posts_per_page' )`, it has to be different than 0 and it works on the search page as well.

I hope everyone looking for the same issue read this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this to get `max_num_pages` in `searchpage.php`

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->max_num_pages;
```

Comment: Did you mean using your code in `functions.php` ?, when I use your code in `functions php`, and echo `$wp_query->max_num_pages;` it prints 0 to page.